# SQL Connection Dialog showing when run .Net Application

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2014

I am getting a strange error when run the .Net Application. When I
   run the application in debug/release mode, an SQL connection dialog
   pops upevery time and when closing the dialog the application is getting
   compiled and getting a failed message "The SQL Server is not
   installed on the local host". But I have installed SQL 2012 on the
   machine. But I have noticed SQL Express is also in the running mode.
   So I stopped running SQL Express in services. Let me know if you need
   any additional information. Please can you help me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the dialog a full SQL connection dialog or a basic windows authentication?.   I expect you cant share your connection string  but I'd like bet it got something to do with this problem.  Is the connection string looking for a specific instance, ie an instance that is only on production?

Comment: Thanks Phil on coming back to me. The issue got resolved there were multiple instances of SQL Server running on my machine and after uninstalling all the existing versions and install the new version the issue got resolved. Thanks for the help.